# How to hide an element if it's being viewed from a certain route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, partials

I've got a partial with a form in it. I would like to have control over which routes admin users are able to view this form in.

There are two routes, advertisements/show, and advertisements/admin-edit. The partial is displayed in both views.

I tried doing

```
<%= unless current_user.admin %>
  # display section of partial
<% end %>
```

but this isn't optimal because it stop admins from being able to test the application from the advertisements/show route.

Is there a way to hide the form if the current path is admin_edit_path?

Comment: your question contradicts itself....

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: "Users who are admins should not be able to view that form" (admins shouldn't see the form) and " it stop admins from being able to test the application from the advertisements/show" (admins should see the form)

Comment: The real solution would be a conditional like you're doing, or to not re-use this partial for the admin page and the non-admin page.

Comment: @sevenseacat. Ah... I meant that admins shouldn't be able to see the form from advertisements/admin-edit. My apologies for being inconsistent. I'll edit it now.

Comment: @sevenseacat. Yeah. I opted for the conditional because removing that form from the partial caused some problems on the front-end.

Answer (score 4):

try this one:

````
<% unless params[:action] == 'edit' && params[:controller] == 'admin' %>
  # display partial
<% end %>```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
<% unless current_page?(controller: 'advertisements', action: 'admin_edit') %>
  #display partial
<% end %>
```